# drag and drop button with angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list and when I select an option I want to to drag it in an other list:
 I tried to do the same example in : http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#!/ but the button is not drapped, I don't know what's wrong. this is my plnkr example, could someone help me please:  https://plnkr.co/edit/O5IWpswzMhGKd7ByM4lP?p=preview

```
<div class="btn btn-primary btn-draggable" data-drag="true" ng-repeat="pref in knowledgemodel" ng-model="list5" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" jqyoui-draggable="{animate:true}" >{{pref.label}}</div><br>
```

Comment: There is an error on the line that says _.contains()... in javascript if you want  to check for a substring, you have to use something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/1789952/886393 .

Comment: @pparas thank you for replying, my first problem is with the button that I can't drag, could you help in this please?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/B52J5mxyEUKk1OMlRlBp?p=preview I add a select2 can I drag the select that I choose?